# dataFrame Перенос значений каждой строчки на n значений вправо. N = число значений nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть массив данных вида:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
df['1'] = np.array([10, 20, 30, np.nan])
df['2'] = np.array([100, 200, np.nan, np.nan])
df['3'] = np.array([1000, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])



    0   1   2   3
0   1   10  100 1000
1   2   20  200 NaN
2   3   30  NaN NaN
3   4   NaN NaN NaN
```

Вопрос: как сделать передвижку не-NaN значений в каждой строке на N вправо, где N - число NaN значений.

То есть получить результат вида:

```
    1   10  100 1000
1   NaN  2   20  200    
2   NaN NaN   3   30    
3   NaN NaN NaN    4
```

Comment: в присвоении `df['1'] = np.array([10, 20, 30, 'NaN'])` - у вас строка "NaN" или все-таки `np.nan`?

Comment: np.nan, вы правы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, так вас устроит?

Исходные данные:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
df['1'] = np.array([10, 20, 30, np.nan])
df['2'] = np.array([100, 200, np.nan, np.nan])
df['3'] = np.array([1000, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
```

то есть такой датафрейм:

```
   0     1      2       3
0  1  10.0  100.0  1000.0
1  2  20.0  200.0     NaN
2  3  30.0    NaN     NaN
3  4   NaN    NaN     NaN
```

И, собственно, преобразование:

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i] = df.loc[i].shift(df.loc[i].isna().sum())
```

Получаем:

```
     0     1      2       3
0  1.0  10.0  100.0  1000.0
1  NaN   2.0   20.0   200.0
2  NaN   NaN    3.0    30.0
3  NaN   NaN    NaN     4.0
```

Comment: Да, этот цикл куда лучше моих костылей. Но я думал, что есть какой-то встроенный метод. Как говорят, если ты в пандас используешь цикл - значит, ты что-то делаешь не так:-)

Comment: Обычно да. если есть возможность использовать векторизированные методы, то нужно ей воспользоваться. но их, к сожалению, не везде можно применить.

Answer (score 2):

По сути дела, это тот же цикл, спрятанный в apply. Но при таком подходе можно собрать все не nan значения направо, даже если они разбросаны по строке, а не расположены в определенном порядке

```
 df.apply(lambda x: \
       pd.Series(x.dropna().values, index=df.columns[-len(x.dropna().values):]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что он идет построчно слева, обнаруживает нан и кидает его в конец на "зеркальную" позицию?

Comment: он берет не наны - `x.dropna().values` -  и ставит их в последние колонки - `-len(x.dropna().values)` - вычисляет сколько нужно колонок от конца, чтоб поместились